# Problems while adding new language in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I need to add french language to my site, it worked and I translated some pages but I could not view the pages using the path segment `/fr`, but only using `&L=6`.
I already have this code in my `setup.ts` file.

```
config {
    sys_language_uid = 9
    language = fr
    locale_all = fr_FR.UTF-8
    htmlTag_setParams = lang="fr" dir="ltr"
    #class="no-js"
}
```

so what can I do?

Comment: I edited your question, but I'm in doubt about your word "extinction". The next meaningful word which came to mind is "extension", but it does not make sense either. Do you mean "path segment"?

Comment: Yes the path segment what i meant, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further details I can only suggest to [update your RealURL configuration](https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/wiki/Configuration-reference#valuemap) accordingly.